# Is the set $\{0,1\}$ opened or closed?

Tags: general-topology

I think it is neither open nor closed because it contains none of boundary points and interior point.
I'm not sure if its correct, help please!

Comment: where?in which topology?

Comment: Sets are not, of themselves, open or closed. They are open or closed in a topological space. For exmaple, if your space is $\{0,1\}$ with any topology, then it is both open and closed.

Comment: As a subset of $\mathbb R$ (with standard topology), $\{0,1\}$ is closed and not open, has no interior points, hence is its own boundary.

Comment: The problem is regarding to a range of a function. The function is  from Rn to R, and the range is {0,1}. We need to prove that no function is continuous in this range

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\{0,1\}$ is closed in $\Bbb R,$ since its complement is $(-\infty,0)\cup(0,1)\cup(1,\infty),$ which is a union of open sets, and so open. Alternately, you can prove that it's closed because it's finite, so has no limit/accumulation points, and so vacuously contains all of its limit/accumulation points.

To show that there is no continuous function $f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$ having range $\{0,1\},$ though, you could make use of a property called *connectedness*, by noting that $\Bbb R^n$ is connected, while $\{0,1\}$ is not, and then using the fact that continuous images of connected sets are connected.

Alternatively, if you're unfamiliar with connectedness, note that $\{0\}$ is both relatively closed and relatively open in $\{0,1\}$--relatively closed because it is closed in $\Bbb R$, and relatively open because $(-\frac12,\frac12)\cap\{0,1\}=\{0\}$. Thus, the preimage of $\{0\}$ under any continuous function $\Bbb R^n\to\{0,1\}$ will be both open and closed in $\Bbb R^n.$ Which subsets of $\Bbb R^n$ are both open and closed? Given the answer to that question, can a continuous function $\Bbb R^n\to\{0,1\}$ be surjective?

Comment: Constant sequences have limits too, so $\{0,1\}$ is the set of limit points of itself ;)

Comment: @AlexR: True, but I was not talking about sequence limits.

Comment: since ℝn and empty set are both open and closed subsets of Rn but neither of them is the inverse of the image {0}. Is this why the function can't be continuous?

Comment: @Iceyyy: Basically. In particular, $\Bbb R^n$ and $\emptyset$ are the **only** subsets of $\Bbb R^n$ that are both open and closed, but the preimage of $\{0\}$ under a surjective function $\Bbb R^n\to\{0,1\}$ cannot be either of these, so such a function can't be continuous.

Answer (score 3):

Assume the metric topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

For a set to be
open, it must contain an open ball around each of its points. This
set does not, so it's definitely not open. Now, consider the complement,
$$
\left\{ 0,1\right\} ^{c}=\mathbb{R}\setminus\left\{ 0,1\right\} =\left(-\infty,0\right)\cup\left(0,1\right)\cup\left(1,\infty\right).
$$
Note that each of those sets is open, the union of open sets is (by
definition) open. So the original set is closed.

Comment: Big fat **assume** here

Answer (score 2):

$\{0, 1\}$ as a two-point-set is closed in *most* topological spaces (like $\mathbb R, \mathbb N$, both with their standard topology) and *can* be open, for example in discrete topological superspaces of $\{0,1\}$ like $\mathbb N$.