# criteria for connectedness

Tags: metric-spaces, proof-writing, connectedness

I have to prove that if, $X$ is not the union of two disjoint non-empty closed subsets of itself, then,

Either $X$ = $\phi$ or the only continuous functions from $X$ to the discrete space {${0,1}$} are the two constant functions.

Attempt at the proof:

Assume that the first one is true, and let $f$:$X$->{${0,1}$} be continuous.

Then f inverse of zero and f inverse of one are both disjoint and closed in $X$

How do i proceed further ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Question about criteria of connectedness](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552984/question-about-criteria-of-connectedness)

Comment: @Don: I disagree. Though they are related, they are about proving different (though equivalent) characterizations of connectedness. That said, I think it *is* a duplicate. I'll try to track it down.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/528899/28900).

Answer (score 1):

Well, show that $$X=f^{-1}(0)\cup f^{-1}(1).$$ What can you then conclude about $f^{-1}(0)$ or $f^{-1}(1),$ since $X$ is connected?